Error in loading Ogre plugins in build directory with CMake
I've create a CMake project that needs Ogre library. I've installed it with vcpkg and then I use it in my CMakeLists.txt, that's like the following one:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION ${PROJECT_CMAKE_VERSION})

project (dynamicmodeltester)

find_package (Boost COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED QUIET)
find_package (imgui CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package (unofficial-imguizmo CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package (implot CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package (OGRE REQUIRED COMPONENTS Bites CONFIG)

include_directories (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../..)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set (PROJECT_SRC
  Options/Application.cpp
  Options/Parser.cpp
  Application.cpp
  LoggerLoader.cpp
  main.cpp
  RepositoryLoader.cpp
  Viewer.cpp
)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRC} ${VERSION_SRC})

target_link_libraries (
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE
  imgui::imgui
  unofficial::imguizmo::imguizmo
  implot::implot
  OgreMain
  Codec_EXR
  OgreBites
  Codec_STBI
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_CXX_STANDARD})

set_target_properties (${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
  #WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON
  MACOSX_BUNDLE ON
)

I can build and run the project, but when it start Ogre gives me following error:

Ogre::InternalErrorException::InternalErrorException: Could not load dynamic library C:/Environments/vcpkg/packages/ogre_x64-windows/debug/etc/ogre/../../plugins/ogre\Plugin_DotScene.  System Error: The specified module could not be found.

I can see the missing library plugin in vcpkg build libraries in my cmake build directory, in C:\my\project\build\debug\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\plugins\ogre
What's the correct way to copy those libraries inside my build directory, so Ogre can find them when executing my program?
I don't know if the problem is the path, because if I copy and paste the plugin path that appears in the error message, I go to the correct directory; the problem seems that my program is looking for Plugin_DotScene, while in the directory I can find Plugin_DotScene_d.dll. I don't know if this is the problem because I've the same also in release mode, where no _d postfix is in the library name. Maybe something related to the .dll extension? I've also tried to copy manually all the files in vcpkg plugins directory into the build one, but nothing changes.


What's the correct way to copy those libraries inside my build directory, so Ogre can find them when executing my program?

Here is the hint documentation, Step 01.06. Try to be done to via the plugins.cfg or plugins_d.cfg (for debug builds) file, and make sure plugin configuration files to the your executing  project folder.
